# Orika - Not working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, orika

I having trouble getting Orika working using eclipse.... I added the maven orika dependencies (1.4.6) and I created a sample junit test

```
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;

public class OrikaTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //System.setProperty(OrikaSystemProperties.COMPILER_STRATEGY,EclipseJdtCompilerStrategy.class.getName());

        MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder()
                .build();

        mapperFactory
            .classMap(PersonDTO.class, PersonEntity.class)
            .field("cellPhone", "phone")
            .byDefault()
            .register();

        PersonDTO dto = new PersonDTO();
        dto.setFirstName("John");
        dto.setLastName("Smith");
        //dto.setRoles(Lists.newArrayList("Role1", "Role2"));
        dto.setCellPhone("845-111-2222");

        MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

        PersonEntity entity = mapper.map(dto, PersonEntity.class);

        assertEquals(entity.getFirstName(), "Jeff");
        assertNotNull("Roles not filled", entity);

    }

}

class PersonDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String cellPhone;
    private List<String> roles;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public String getCellPhone() {
        return cellPhone;
    }
    public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }
}

class PersonEntity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private List<String> roles;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I get the following exception:

> ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class PersonDTO is not accessible
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:105)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1372)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.build(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1199)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.getMapperFacade(DefaultMapperFactory.java:859)
>       at OrikaTest.test(OrikaTest.java:37)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class PersonDTO is not accessible
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.JavassistCompilerStrategy.assureTypeIsAccessible(JavassistCompilerStrategy.java:155)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:58)
>       ... 27 more

Note: I see in the console eclipse printing the defined mapping.  However, I get the above error when executing:

```
MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
```

If I attempt to use the EclipseJdtCompilerStrategy, by setting the system property, I get a different exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/INameEnvironment;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IErrorHandlingPolicy;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ICompilerRequestor;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/IProblemFactory;)V
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.EclipseJdtCompiler.(EclipseJdtCompiler.java:87)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.EclipseJdtCompiler.(EclipseJdtCompiler.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.EclipseJdtCompilerStrategy.(EclipseJdtCompilerStrategy.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.UtilityResolver.resolveUtility(UtilityResolver.java:123)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.UtilityResolver.getDefaultCompilerStrategy(UtilityResolver.java:51)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory$MapperFactoryBuilder.(DefaultMapperFactory.java:310)
>       at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory$Builder.(DefaultMapperFactory.java:587)
>       at OrikaTest.test(OrikaTest.java:22)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show the code of PersonDTO

Comment: Added the full class, including the PersonDTO and imports ... thx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the

```
class PersonDTO is not accessible at
    ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.JavassistCompilerStrategy.assureTypeIsAccessible(JavassistCompilerStrategy.java:155)
```

Your `PersonDTO` class is package-visible, so Orika code cannot access it from its package. Make it a `public class` and that problem should go away. For reference, see specifically [that line](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/orika-1.4.x/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/impl/generator/JavassistCompilerStrategy.java#L155) in Orika code.

That happens when you are using the default (Javassist) compiler.

For the Eclipse compiler, double-check that you added the relevant Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
   <artifactId>orika-eclipse-tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.6</version><!-- should correspond to your core Orika version -->
</dependency>
```

and enable the compiler when creating the mapperFactory

```
MapperFactory factory = 
    new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder()
            .compilerStrategy(new EclipseJdtCompilerStrategy())
            .build();
```

The system property should be used as a fallback, so rather use the builder approach above.

For details see the [Troubleshooting Guide](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/troubleshooting.html) "Enable step-debugging" section.

Comment: Your awesome!! Thanks for your help